# Running Multiple Process At The Same Time And Returning the Results

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to execute a function at the same time with different arguments and also have to get the return values back in my main. A pseudocode for my problem is

```
def Function(data):
      print("Function Running With Values" , data[0],"and",data[1],"At timestamp : " ,time.time())
      return data[0]+data[1]


Results= []
Values= [ [1,2],[2,3],[4,5],[1,4]]
#calling function for all Values and return the result in results variable in sequence.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "*at the same time*":

If a *sequential processing* is fine [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map)

```
Results = list(map(Function, Values))
print(Results)
```

or more *pythonic* a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions)

```
Results = [Function(value) for value in Values]
print(Results)
```

gives you the following output

```
Function Running With Values 1 and 2 At timestamp :  1605276375.4642859
Function Running With Values 2 and 3 At timestamp :  1605276375.4645345
Function Running With Values 4 and 5 At timestamp :  1605276375.4647174
Function Running With Values 1 and 4 At timestamp :  1605276375.4648669
[3, 5, 9, 5]
```

If you actually want *multiprocessing* then [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html)

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool() as p:
    Results = list(p.map(Function, Values))

print(Results)
```

or [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html)

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

with ProcessPoolExecutor() as p:
    Results = list(p.map(Function, Values))

print(Results)
```

gives you output like

```
Function Running With Values 1 and 2 At timestamp :  1605276375.4532914
Function Running With Values 4 and 5 At timestamp :  1605276375.4547572
Function Running With Values 2 and 3 At timestamp :  1605276375.4549458
Function Running With Values 1 and 4 At timestamp :  1605276375.456188
[3, 5, 9, 5]
```

If you want multiprocessing then you should look a bit deeper into it to make sure nothing goes wrong and the processing is indeed faster. But your example is a classic [*MapReduce*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) scenario that should work fine.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank You.! Solved my problem perfectly..! by 'at the same time' I mean't multiprocessing only :)

Comment: @TigerStrom Then sorry for the other stuff! Some additional points: You need to play around a bit to achieve the optimal speed. Both, `mp.Pool` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, allow for specifiying the max. number of process (workers, ...) that should run concurrently. The standard is the number of cpus (cores) your machine has, but that isn't always the best choice. `.map` has an optional argument `chunksize`. I found that setting it to something like length of the argument list divided by the specified number of processes often the best choice. ...